# How to achieve RTSP web-assembly module

Tags: rtsp, webassembly

I have an application where Wasm can handle video & audio codes, which can be passed to Media Source Ext for rendering purposes. To get RTSP & RTP stream data on the browser, needs RTSP wasm module which can consume RTSP streams.

Is there any way we can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

WebAssembly itself does not provide any APIs for interacting with the browser or OS.  All I/O must be handled via imports and exports.  So you would need to implement JavaScript functions that send and receive the data and pass it in and out of your WebAssembly module.

Comment: do you have any reference for such javascript code?